# Solve for a complex number $z$ in $z^6 = z^{14}$

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

I tried:

$$z^6 = z^{14} \Leftrightarrow \\
z^6 = z^{8}\cdot z^6 \Leftrightarrow \\
1 = z^8 \Leftrightarrow \\
1 = z \Leftrightarrow \\
1 = x+yi \Leftrightarrow \\
1 = x  \land y = 0$$

But apparently this is wrong http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(x%2Byi)%5E6+%3D+(x%2Byi)%5E14

What did I do wrong?

Comment: $1=e^{2\pi ki}$ for any integer $k$.

Comment: You actually have $z^6=0$ (with one complex solution) or $z^8=1$ (with eight complex solutions)

Answer (score 3):

This is the key error: $1=z^8\iff1=z$.
The eighth order equation ought to have eight solutions.
Can you find the eight solutions by using polar form ($z=re^{i\phi}$)?
It should be straightforward.

And there is an algebra error.
You can only cancel $z^6$ if $z^6\neq0$.
This gives makes you miss one solution.

Comment: But when I take the eighth root from both sides shouldn't that remove the exponent from z?

Comment: @MarkRead No! Simple example: If you solve $z^2=1$ for $z\in\mathbb R$, you can't just take the power out. You would miss the solution $z=-1$. It's the same general phenomenon here. Try taking a complex number in polar form ($r\geq0$, $\phi\in[0,2\pi)$) and calculate what the eighth power is. You'll see several solutions.

Comment: Ah, it makes sense now. Ok i'll give it a try.

Answer (score 3):

Note that
$$
z^6 = z^{14}\iff z^6(1-z^8)=0\iff z^6=0\quad\text{or}\quad z^8=1
$$
Hence the solutions are $z=0$ along with the eight roots of unity. When you divide by $z^6$ you assume that $z\neq 0$ and hence miss a solution in the end.